# MEF ComposeExportedValue method

Tags: .net, silverlight, mef

I have the following situation :

I have in UserControl A , in this user control I manage selecting a list of contacts for sending email. I added to its ViewModelA an Action so after filling the contacts I can call this action and this will move the operation with the contacts list to the control which call the UserControlA

```
 [Import(AllowDefault = true, AllowRecomposition = true)]
 public Action<IEnumerable<Contact>> ActionContactMethod
```

In UserControl B which contains UserControlA I declared a method `void Send(Action<IEnumerable<Contact>> contacts)` which is the same signature of the action in UserControl A.

I use MEF composition container to compose it :

```
CompositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue(new Action<IEnumerable<Contact>>(Send));
```

This way , when the user choose his contacts then the Action in ViewModelA which wired with the method Send in ViewModelB will happen and the Send method will be called .

The first time I see the recomposition occured and the method send is wired correctly, the second time I'm trying to use the ComposeExportedValue I get an exception, because there is already an Export definition to the `Action<IEnumerable<Contact>>`.

How I can remove this part from the container so I can compose it again, or if there is another workaround. I used the Compose and the ComposePart method but the recompositions dosn't happen this way.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ComposeExportedValue<T>` doesn't give you enough control over the `ComposablePart` instances used during composition.  You can control recomposition using `CompositionBatch` instances. Here is an example class:

```
[Export]
public class Broker
{
    [Import(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    public Action<string> Writer { get; set; }
}
```

I've specified a property which is actual a delegate, now look at the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        var part1 = batch.AddExportedValue<Action<string>>(ConsoleWrite);
        container.Compose(batch);

        var broker = container.GetExportedValue<Broker>();
        broker.Writer("Hello");

        var batch2 = new CompositionBatch(null, new[] { part1 });
        batch2.AddExportedValue<Action<string>>(ConsoleWrite2);
        container.Compose(batch2);

        broker.Writer("Goodbye");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ConsoleWrite(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + " from ConsoleWrite");
    }

    static void ConsoleWrite2(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + " from ConsoleWrite2");
    }
}
```

What I've done here, is I've created two separate batches, one which allows me to compose my original delegate, wired up to `ConsoleWrite`, and one which allows me to remove my original delegate, and then compose my second delegate, `ConsoleWrite2`. During the first composition, my delegate is wired up in my `Broker` instance. Now, because I have specified that `[Import]` to be recomposable, when I compose my second batch, it removes my original part (which is my delegate), and composes my new part (which is my new delegate).

Comment: Thanks allot . I have one comment here , you used the part1 instance in the second batch to remove it an then compose new part . In my case I have this code you wrote in a user control , each time I call to show it it will be created so I don't have part one in the new instance, how can get part1 programatically from the container . Thanks.